# Using Keras to build CNN-LSTM with video frame sequence: InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor

Tags: video, tensorflow, keras, pre-trained-model

I'm building a CNN-LSTM network in Keras+Tensorflow using video frames as input. I'm setting up the network as shown below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import cv2

video = keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, 299,299,3),name='video_input')

cnn = keras.applications.InceptionV3(weights='imagenet',
                                 include_top='False',
                                 pooling='avg')

cnn.trainable = False
encoded_frame = keras.layers.TimeDistributed(cnn)(video)
encoded_vid = keras.layers.LSTM(256)(encoded_frame)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(encoded_vid)
```

Some of the tensor properties are below:

```
video
<tf.Tensor 'video_input:0' shape=(?, ?, ?, 299, 299, 3) dtype=float32>

cnn.input
<tf.Tensor 'input_1:0' shape=(?, 299, 299, 3) dtype=float32>

cnn.output
<tf.Tensor 'predictions/Softmax:0' shape=(?, 1000) dtype=float32>    

encoded_frame
<tf.Tensor 'time_distributed_1/Reshape_1:0' shape=(?, ?, 1000) dtype=float32>

encoded_vid
<tf.Tensor 'lstm_1/TensorArrayReadV3:0' shape=(?, 256) dtype=float32>

outputs
<tf.Tensor 'dense_1/Relu:0' shape=(?, 128) dtype=float32>
```

Now I build the model and fit the data:

```
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[video],outputs=outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='mean_squared_logarithmic_error')
# Generate random targets
y = np.random.random(size=(128,)) 
y = np.reshape(y,(-1,128))
model.fit(x=frame_sequence, y=y, validation_split=0.0,shuffle=False, batch_size=1)
```

where `frame_sequence` is a sequence of video frames from one video:

```
frame_sequence.shape
(1, 48, 299, 299, 3)
```

All seems well up to the training step `model.fit`, where I get an error attributed to the `input_1` placeholder in the InceptionV3 model input:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1' with dtype float
 [[Node: input_1 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Where do I feed a value for `input_1` within Keras or where in setting up the network am I going wrong?

Update: Training works without error if I build my CNN from scratch or if I use VGG instead of loading InceptionV3. For example, replacing InceptionV3 with:

```
cnn = Sequential()
cnn.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(229, 229, 3)))
cnn.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
cnn.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
cnn.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
cnn.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
cnn.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
cnn.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
cnn.add(Flatten())
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/Feynman27/77e94295eb386abec9cc67a6f5ae47e0) is a minimal example to reproduce the error.

Comment: Both models from your minimal example are working for me. `Python 3.6.3`, `Keras==2.1.5` and `tensorflow==1.6.0`.

Comment: How did you prepare your data?